# IE document mode and iframes

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, meta-tags, x-ua-compatible

I've read a few answers on here, but not sure I'm fully understanding them.... I have a web page that needs to be in document mode 5, there's no way around that, and within that page, I have a iframe, that I want to set `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` just so I can make the google maps API that I'm using in the iframe work.

I'm not sure if firstly, I can set the document mode of a child where the parent is already set, and secondly, if I can how?

We are using IE11, and the pages are built using IBM Domino, traditional HTML.

The iframe code is simply:

```
<iframe id="PropertySearchResults" class="MELSubFrame" src="<Computed Value>"></iframe>
```

And tips or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible, you'd need to have a real IE<8 to run a different document mode in the iframe.

Comment: So are we saying there is no way, AT ALL, that I can display content on a webpage that is set to document mode 5, but needs to be emulated for IE11/Edge just for this one section?